# How do I install this library for C, linux (preferably to use in codeblocks but if not however else you do it)

Tags: c, codeblocks, linux-mint, firmata

https://github.com/jdourlens/FirmataC   I am trying to install this to use on Linux mint, but I don't know how to install it to use. I have downloaded the files and included the headers and source files in a "project" in codeblocks, but it doesn't compile, keeps going into more and more includes within the files to not be found. Personally, alot of github projects/folders for libraries I always find it incredibly hard to use or install it on both windows/linux. If its a generic and common way of installing these libraries, how do I do this?

Errors:

```
main.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `firmata_new'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `firmata_pull'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `firmata_pinMode'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `firmata_digitalWrite'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `firmata_digitalWrite'
```

Comment: *it doesn't compile*. Show what you have done and what the exact errors are.

Comment: Please add the command line(s) you used when attempting to compile your project.

Comment: gcc main.c -o main

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FirmataC project comes with a `Makefile`, which allows you to build the library. To do so, clone the project and run `make` in the project directory. Then, you can link to this library when you compile by running `gcc main.c -L <path-to-clone-dir> -I <path-to-clone-dir>/inclues -lfirmatac -o main` where ` is the path to which you cloned the FirmataC project.

It is also good to note that many `Makefile`s (but not this one) will provide a `make install` command, which allows you to install the library on a system level. If you are using a library that allows it, running `make install` allows you to simply do `gcc main.c -l<library-name> -o main`.

Comment: You may also want to mention `make install` which installs to a standardized include directory, after which the command-line `gcc main.c  -lfirmatac -o main` becomes sufficient.

Comment: @nanofarad, this library actually doesn't provide an install target in their makefile, but I will definitely add that as a note for other libraries.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Just a side question, when running ```make install``` if it installs it on a system level, does that mean that in a ```new project``` in code::blocks, I don't have to do any includes or linker stuff, the ```#include``` will recognise ```firmatac.h```

Comment: I've never used code::blocks, but my guess is you would still need to add `-l<libname>` to the compiler flags. It is possible the IDE will do that automatically, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: Just a weird thing i've found. A small snipped of code posted works and then stops working after a few seconds. Its a simple "turn LED on an off every second". The program works for a few loops and then just stops working